# enable second dropdown once something gets selected in dropdown 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to enable my second `dropdown` only when something gets selected in `dropdown 1`. By default it is disabled.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk5e9/77/) what I am trying in fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   if ($(.test).is(":selected")) { 
      $(".test1").prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
      $(".test1").prop("disabled", true);  
   }   
 }
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler to handle change event

```js
$('.test').change(function() {
  $(".test1").prop("disabled", this.value == -1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select class="test1" disabled>
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Suraj : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `change()` Event Handler

```
$('.test').change(function() {
if(this.value == -1){
      $(".test1").prop("disabled", true);
}else{
    $(".test1").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

});

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rk5e9/80/)**

Comment: Once I select default again the second should get disabled. Although got it working. Thanks